# Running into error with BASH script with permission denied, but when running the command directly in bash shell its getting executed

Tags: windows, bash, shell, scripting

When running below command directly in bash shell, I am able to get the output. But when I am passing it via BASH script getting access denied. Any help would be appreciated

```
$ jq  -r '.id' Repooutput.txt
dad04f6d-4e06-4420-b0bc-cb2dcfee2dcf
```

Error:

```
$ sh test.sh
test.sh: line 3: /c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/jq: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the naming convention of JQ inside BASH folder path, because of which the script was unable to pick the command. Renaming the JQ within BASH folder resolved this

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that when executing the script with `sh test.sh` we're asking the POSIX interpreter (shell) to execute the content on the script, while when executing it with `./test.sh` we're asking the script to "execute itself".

For the latter, the file needs to have `execution` permissions, which you can add with

```
chmod +x test.sh
```